# Shall I use output buffering (ob_start) or not

Tags: php, output-buffering, ob-start

I have amended my PHP code in order to avoid using output buffering after finding out that it denotes a poor coding pattern. But still am using it where it is needed inevitably.

But, some articles say that using output buffering is beneficial as it combines the output into one , by default the output is broken into html and headers separately and is then displayed on the browser, but output buffering eliminates this breakage process, thus augmenting the speed of output display to the end user.

All this article stuff has left me in a dilemma to use or completely avoid output buffering. Am not sure if am completely right about its working and the points I have mentioned.
So please guide me accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are times where the use of output buffering is a good thing to use, but to use it as lots of people do (the **lazy** way of not having to send headers before output for example) is not the right time.

The example you give, I do not know much about, but if its optimal, it might be one of the times where its good to use.
Its not forbidden to use `ob_start()`, its just the "*wrong way*" to use it the way I stated earlier.

The optimization you mention feels like a very low-level optimization, you might get a tad bit 'quicker' output, but there is usually *a lot* of other optimizations in a standard php-script that could speed it up before that is worth looking at!

*edit:*
Example of a small script that don't use send headers before output vs one that do:

```
<?php
$doOutput = true;
$doRedirect = true;
$output = "";
if($doOutput == true){ 
    // $doOutput is true, so output is supposed to be printed.
    $output = "Some output yay!";
}
if($doRedirect == true){ 
    // but $doRedirect is also true, so redirect will be done.
    header("location:anotherpage.php");  // This will not produce an error cause there was no output!
    exit();
}
// The echo below will not be printed in the example, cause the $doRedirect var was true.
echo $output;
```

Instead of (this case will produce a header sent after output error):

```
<?php
$doOutput = true;
$doRedirect = true; 
if($doOutput == true){ 
    //Output will be printed, cause $doOutput is true.
    echo "Some output yay!";
}
if($doRedirect == true){ 
    // but $doRedirect is also true, so redirect will be done.
    header("location:anotherpage.php");  // This will produce an error cause output was already printed.
    exit();
}
```

*edit2:* Updated with a more obvious example!

Comment: ok sir, times when am using it then I place it at the top of my script as the first line in all my php script files ...is it right or not? is there some other way out? What's the right and correct way to use it. Please guide me thoroughly if possible. Am really stuck at it.

Comment: Well, depends on the reason you put it at top of all files!
Is it cause you get a 'headers can not be sent after output' (or similar) message? Then I would recommend another approach in the code. I have never encountered a situation where I HAD to send headers after output.

Comment: Yes sir, you're exactly right...I get the same error...what would be my new approach then....currently I redirect the page using header('location.....') if some error occurs while saving user data at my back-end php script

Comment: Well, don't do any output before redirecting. It should not be needed, cause if you redirect, the user will not see any of the output anyways. You could for example; store all data in variables, and echo them out when you reach the "output part" of the script (which would then be after headers are sent, that is, the output is actually echoed IF the headers are NOT sent).

Comment: Added very simple example.

Comment: ok sir, I would shift my redirection code above the html thus removing the output buffering usage

Comment: Please feel free to mark answer as correct if it gave you what you where looking for! :)

Comment: Sir, if am right , in the 2nd part the error would occur...so instead of using ob_start in the second part, I should go for the first approach according to you?

Comment: Right, updated with a more obvious example and comments. Hope its more clear :P

Comment: Sir, I added a last explanatory line , please check if am right there too! :)